# Create internal mouse events in shape class

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mouseevent, shapes

I'm creating a custom `Shape` class:

```
public class CustomBox : Shape
{
    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get
        {
            Stroke = Brushes.Red;
            var pathGeometry = new PathGeometry();

            pathGeometry.AddGeometry(new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(new Point(100, 200), new Point(400, 400)));

            var formattedText = new FormattedText("CustomBox", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, new Typeface("Times New-Roman"), 14, Brushes.Red);
            var textGeometry = formattedText.BuildGeometry(new Point(100, 200));

            pathGeometry.AddGeometry(textGeometry);
            return pathGeometry;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to add/override/implement internal `Mouse` events such as `MouseDown`, `MouseUp`, `MouseMove` etc. which will define the behavior of the `CustomBox` object.

For example:

I wish to add a "behavior" which occurs when I hover over the object - the result will be that the `Rectangle` will be highlighted (by increasing the `StrokeThickness` for instance).

Can such functions be added without having to register the object to `Mouse` events externally (from the class which creates the `CustomBox` and adds it to the `Canvas`)?

Comment: Looks like XY problem. Your example could be implemented as a style trigger. If you want to react other mouse events, just override appropriate `OnPreviewMouse***`/`OnMouse***` methods, e.g. `OnMouseMove`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the next:
 1. Xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="CustomShapeSoHelpAttempt.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:customShapeSoHelpAttempt="clr-namespace:CustomShapeSoHelpAttempt"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <customShapeSoHelpAttempt:CustomBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="#00FFFFFF"/>
</Grid></Window>
```

2. CustomBox code:

```
 public class CustomBox : Shape
{
    private Brush _originalBrush;
    private double _originalThickness;

    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get
        {

            var pathGeometry = new PathGeometry();

            pathGeometry.AddGeometry(new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), new Point(200, 200))));

            var formattedText = new FormattedText("CustomBox", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                new Typeface("Times New-Roman"), 14, Brushes.Black);
            var textGeometry = formattedText.BuildGeometry(new Point(0, 0));

            pathGeometry.AddGeometry(textGeometry);
            return pathGeometry;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseEnter(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseEnter(e);
        _originalThickness = StrokeThickness;
        StrokeThickness = 2;
        _originalBrush = Fill;
        Fill = Brushes.Aqua;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        StrokeThickness = _originalThickness;
        Fill = _originalBrush;
    }


}
```

As you can see, you can override all control related mouse event handlers and to perform your logic there. All this due to the fact that your controls derives from Shape control and have all its event handlers.
I'll glad to help if you will have problems with the code. 
Regards.